# Redirect all ARP traffic from eth0 to eth1

Tags: iptables, firewall, arp

I would like to redirect ARP traffic, but I'm struggling with arptables and ebtables.

I have 2 interfaces:

```
eth0 10.10.10.25
eth1 10.10.10.20
```

Both in `10.10.10.0/24`

I want to redirect the `ARP traffic` from `eth0` to `eth1`. I was trying something like that:

```
ebtables -A PREROUTING -p arp -I eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT.
```

but I'm a big new to `iptables/ebtables` and I'm just learning about them.